# How to add an image on top of another with Magento/PHP?

Tags: php, css, zend-framework, magento

I have this code which is pretty easy, it adds an image to the side of another image depending on a boolean magento attribute.

But because we are running a ecommerce store, it would be more attractive to the users top put the image on top of the product. To combine them together.

I wonder if with PHP its possible to do that.
Somebody suggested to do with CSS overlying images?

```
<div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>

        </div>


<?php $Deal = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('deal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>

<?php if($Deal == 'Yes'){ ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/icon-deal.gif') ?>" >
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

CSS

```
.product-img-box{position: relative;}
.overlay{z-index: 100; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;}
```

PHP

```
<div class="product-img-box">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>

    <?php $Deal = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('deal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>

    <?php if($Deal == 'Yes'){ ?>
        <img class="overlay" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/icon-deal.gif') ?>" >
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: does this center the second image horizontally and vertically on top of the first image?

Comment: @Locaaaaa That depends on a number of things. This example assumes that the first image is positioned at the very top left corner of the div with a class name of "product-img-box". You can adjust the position of the second image by changing the pixel positions of the left: **0px**; and top: **0px**;.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible with PHP, but I suppose that with CSS you can overlay the 2nd image on top of the first one.

Comment: actually it makes a lot of sense, but I have no idea how to do that with CSS